# How to verify RSA fingerprint for Linux AWS instance from Windows

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, rsa, aws-cli

The instructions for connecting to AWS Linux AMI states that when using putty, you should locate the SSH HOST KEY FINGERPRINTS section and note the RSA fingerprint.

I am running the "aws ec2 get-console-output ..." CLI command but see nothing that looks like this fingerprint in the console output?

I had then thought that perhaps "SSH HOST KEY FINGERPRINTS" was a putty command or a command I run from a Windows prompt, but that doesn't work either.

So putty is showing me an RSA fingerprint on first connection - but I have no way of checking at the moment.

Amazon docs:

[Click here for image from AWS Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Osm6.png)

Answer (score 0):

The message seems to have changed, but the documentation has not. Look for lines like "Generating public/private rsa key pair". There will be several, one with "rsa", another with "dsa" and a third with "ecdsa". For example:

```
Generating public/private ecdsa key pair.
Your identification has been saved in /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.
Your public key has been saved in /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
e8:04:9e:c5:a3:8a:2d:31:36:cf:a6:86:2f:f6:51:89 root@ip-10-87-121-154
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ECDSA  256]---+
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|  .    0     .   |
| . oo.. E . S .  |
|o  +.+o  . . +   |
| o. +oo  .  .    |
|  o.o  ... .     |
|.o.+.. .. . .    |
+-----------------+
```

The key you're looking for would in this case be `e8:04:9e:c5:a3:8a:2d:31:36:cf:a6:86:2f:f6:51:89`.

It's a much less convenient and obvious format than the old one.